# Spherical Cap containing Independent points in Erdös-Bollobás Graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, spheres, ramsey-theory

This is in reference to the paper [On a Ramsey-Turán Type Problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiP4-LpyOaCAxW77zgGHaGpA6kQFnoECB0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fusers.renyi.hu%2F%7Ep_erdos%2F1976-20.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0yIhacMa12tGfmFC2JtQJ5&opi=89978449)

On Page 3, the authors claim that the maximum number of independent points in the constructed graph is atmost equal to the area of the spherical cap $C$ with $\operatorname{diam}(C) = 2 - \frac{2 \epsilon}{3\sqrt{k}}$

I can't understand how the authors can claim this at all. I have been stuck on this problem for the past month. Any help is appreciated